# Disabling pre-loaded rows while being able to add new rows in a Kendo-Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I want all rows in the grid that is loaded from the database to be locked/ disabled from editing. At the same time you should be able to add new rows and edit the rows that have not yet been saved to the database. Rows are added inline.

Answer (score 0):

you should make the column editable by default. Then you should bind to the edit event of the Grid, determine whether the current item is new and make the input readonly if needed.

```
.Events(e => e.Edit("onGridEdit")


function onGridEdit(e) {
  if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
   $("input[name=firstName]").attr("readonly", true);//for text/number inputs
   $("#id").kendoDropDownList({ enable: false });//for dropdowns
  }
}
```